# Python Dictionaries and Printing Out Elements with Formatting

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, formatting

Hello guys ı am trying to learn dictionaries and ı have dictionary like this.

```
myContacts = {"Fred": 7235591, "Marry": 3841212,
               "Bob": 3841212, "Sarah": 2213278}
```

I writed this codes and its prints out all names and numbers from given dictionary.
How can ı print out like this;

For example:

```
Bob 384-1212
```

How can ı put "-" that think into the middle.

my codes;

```
def printAll(contacts):
    print("All names and numbers:")
    for key in sorted(contacts):
        print("%-10s  %d" % (key,contacts[key]))
printAll(myContacts)
```

prints out;

```
All names and numbers:
Bob         3841212
Fred        7235591
Marry       3841212
Sarah       2213278
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the number to string and then slice it in the middle:

```
myContacts = {"Fred": 7235591, "Marry": 3841212,
               "Bob": 3841212, "Sarah": 2213278}

def printAll(contacts):
    print("All names and numbers:")
    for key in sorted(contacts):
        s = str(contacts[key])
        firstpart, secondpart = s[:len(s)//2], s[len(s)//2:]
        print('{:<10} {}-{}'.format(key,  firstpart, secondpart))

printAll(myContacts)
```

Prints:

```
All names and numbers:
Bob        384-1212
Fred       723-5591
Marry      384-1212
Sarah      221-3278
```